# Expand parameter in quotes in zsh

Tags: zsh, arguments, parameter, whitespace

I want to pass function arguments to zsh’s `emulate` to evaluate a command in bash emulation:

```zsh
$ .bash() { emulate bash -c "$*" }
$ .bash 'source /path/to/script.sh'
```

It’s ok but I want this without quotes like a precommand modifier (to use syntax highlighting, completion, etc.) as in

```zsh
$ .bash source /path/to/script.sh
```

The problem arises when a command line contains quoted spaces:

```zsh
$ .bash source /path/to/"script with spaces".sh
$ # I want it to expand to
$ emulate bash -c 'source /path/to/"script with spaces".sh'
$ # or the like
```

I tried to play with different quotes and with `${(qq)*}` expansion flags.
No good so far.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have some success with

```
.bash() { emulate bash -c "$(echo ${(qq)@})" }
```